# Redirect 301 works fine?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, global-asax, blogengine.net

I added into my global.asax a 301 redirect from subdirectory to root .. www.informarea.it/blogengine to www.informarea.it
When I write in browser the name of the site: for example:

www.informarea.it / BlogEngine, the redirect happens perfectly and the link change in www.informarea.it,

when i write a old post in browser i dont see the redirect, i see the content of post but the word blogengine is present,

the same when i go on a referral site and I click on an old post in page appears www.informarea.it/ BlogEngine / prova.aspx and not www.informarea.it / prova.aspx. ... the strange is that i see the post...
but this is normal?

then
I currently have 1400 and 1000 duplicate description tags duplicate title tags ......

All is normal or there is some error??

the code is this..

```
string thisUrl = app.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();

if (thisUrl.Contains("http://www.informarea.it/blogengine"))
{

  HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
  HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 301;
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location",thisUrl.Replace("http://www.informarea.it/blogengine","http://www.informarea.it"));
}
```

HttpContext context = app.Context;

can you help me
thank you

Fabry

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a HHTP Module for Redirect instead of in the global.

Here is a link on how to do that:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/110595/Handling-301-Redirects-in-ASP-NET-3-5

Having the redirect in the global does not really work for directories.

Also having it in the http module gets redirected before it hits the global file.